# Server Essentials Client Backups Failing

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-essentials

All the client backups are failing for some reason. I didn't set up the server but from what I can tell it has never worked.

I checked the server essentials event logs on a client and the server and noticed the following errors...

Client (Same on all clients):

> Backup job 0 on SERVER did not succeed.
>
> Reason: NotConfigured,

Server:

> The Windows Server Essentials Computer Backup Service received a cancel process message from CLIENT.
>
> Reason: 11.

I'm a bit of a noob it has to be said with windows server but from what I can see, backup is configured correctly. Can any one offer any suggestions as to what I should check or what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to disable/re-enable client computer backup and check the result.

Also, on the client, please make sure that Windows Server Essentials Client Computer Management Service is running, or, you may try to manually re-start this service and check the result.

Besides, confirm that if the suggestions mentioned in below article would be helpful.

Troubleshoot computer backup and restore errors in Windows Server Essentials:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj593220(v=ws.11).aspx

Best Regards,
Eve Wang

Answer (score 0):

*Can any one offer any suggestions as to what I should check or what might be wrong here?*

Just some general recommendations:

- check the hard drive partitions and ensure they are all NTFS
- run `chkdsk /f /r` and make sure there are no bad sectors
- make sure the clients are not set to go into sleep mode (configure this in Power Options)